# Super simply assembly instruction

Tags: assembly, x86

Consider the following code, in C :

```
unsigned int func(int *ptr, unsigned int j)
{
    unsigned int res = j;
    int i = ptr[j+1]; // <== HERE

    for(; i<8; ++i)
        res >>= 1;

    return res;
}
```

Knowing that `j` is located in `%ecx` and `ptr` in `%eax`, what is the assembly instruction to copy `ptr[j+1]` in `%ecx`? And most of all, why?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Using

```
gcc -g bla.c -c -o bla.o
objdump -dS bla.o
```

I got

```
[...]
unsigned int func(int *ptr, unsigned int j)
{
0:   55                      push   %rbp
1:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
4:   48 89 7d e8             mov    %rdi,-0x18(%rbp)
8:   89 75 e4                mov    %esi,-0x1c(%rbp)
 unsigned int res = j;
b:   8b 45 e4                mov    -0x1c(%rbp),%eax
e:   89 45 fc                mov    %eax,-0x4(%rbp)
 int i = ptr[j+1]; // <== HERE
11:   8b 45 e4                mov    -0x1c(%rbp),%eax
14:   83 c0 01                add    $0x1,%eax
17:   89 c0                   mov    %eax,%eax
19:   48 8d 14 85 00 00 00    lea    0x0(,%rax,4),%rdx
20:   00 
21:   48 8b 45 e8             mov    -0x18(%rbp),%rax
25:   48 01 d0                add    %rdx,%rax
28:   8b 00                   mov    (%rax),%eax
2a:   89 45 f8                mov    %eax,-0x8(%rbp)

  for(; i<8; ++i)
2d:   eb 07                   jmp    36 <func+0x36>
      res >>= 1;
2f:   d1 6d fc                shrl   -0x4(%rbp)
[...]
```

From this we can see the following location of the variable in the stack frame:

```
res :  -0x4(%rbp)
i   :  -0x8(%rbp)
ptr : -0x18(%rbp)
j   : -0x1c(%rbp)
```

So the sequence of instructions is

```
mov    -0x1c(%rbp),%eax       %eax = j
add    $0x1,%eax              %eax++
mov    %eax,%eax              cast to 64bits of %eax
lea    0x0(,%rax,4),%rdx      %rdx = %rax*4     (4 = sizeof(int))
mov    -0x18(%rbp),%rax       %rax = ptr
add    %rdx,%rax              %rax = %rax + %rdx     = ptr + i 
mov    (%rax),%eax            %rax = *(%rax)         = *(ptr+i)
mov    %eax,-0x8(%rbp)        i = %rax
```

Does that answer your question ?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using AT&T '%reg' notation, I'll assume you're using GCC on IA32 (386+).

First - I'm not sure why you would 'know' `j` is in `%ecx` and `ptr` is in `%eax`. For example, the ELF i386 ABI would have `j` @ `8(%esp)` and `ptr` @ `4(%esp)` on the stack at entry. Let's compile with a realistic `-O2 -march=i386` optimization (for a leaf function), and leave in the relevant parts:

```
func:
        movl    8(%esp), %eax
        movl    4(%esp), %edx
        movl    4(%edx,%eax,4), %edx
        cmpl    $7, %edx
        jg      .L2
        .p2align 2,,3
.L3:
        shrl    %eax
        incl    %edx
        cmpl    $8, %edx
        jne     .L3
.L2:
        ret
```

You'll see the compiler has generated an efficient `movl offset(base, index, scale), dest` instruction! From `%eax`, `%edx` you can verify this is: `mov 4(ptr, j, 4), dest` - or the memory at the address: `ptr + j * 4 + 4` is loaded to `dest`. An `[unsigned] int` is `(4)` bytes, so this is: `ptr[j + 1]`. In this case, the compiler has allocated `%edx` as `dest`, and you can follow the rest of assembly at your leisure.

Now - we can force the issue with GCC and [inline assembly](http://locklessinc.com/articles/gcc_asm/). `j` in `%ecx`, `ptr` in `%eax`, and we'll re-use `%eax` as the destination - since we don't care about `ptr` anymore...

```
unsigned int func(int *ptr, unsigned int j)
{
    unsigned int res = j;
    int i;

    __asm__ ("movl 4(%%eax,%%ecx,4), %%eax" /* OR: "movl 4(%0,%1,4), %0" */
             : "=a" (i) : "c" (j), "0" (ptr));

    for(; i<8; ++i)
        res >>= 1;

    return res;
}
```

And GCC (with `"-O2 -march=i386"`) generates:

```
func:
        movl    8(%esp), %ecx
        movl    4(%esp), %eax
        movl 4(%eax,%ecx,4), %eax
        cmpl    $7, %eax
        jg      .L2
        .p2align 2,,3
.L3:
        shrl    %ecx
        incl    %eax
        cmpl    $8, %eax
        jne     .L3
.L2:
        movl    %ecx, %eax
        ret
```

Notice that `j` has been preserved in `%ecx` for the loop, and `i` in `%eax`. The calling conventions require `%eax` to hold the return value, hence the `movl %ecx, %eax` instruction. Using `%ecx` as `dest` would have been less efficient, as we want to keep `res = j` for the loop.

So, the compiler generated slightly better code than that using 'assumed' registers. Not surprising, as this sort of register allocation and propagation is something that modern compilers do very well.